# Add scroll controller to CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, uicollectionview, scrollbar

I have a Collection View in a ViewController, with a Pan Gesture Recognizer that manages the reordering of the cells. Because of that to scroll the Collection View I want to add a "scroll controller" on the side of the Collection View, like Noteshelf app, as showing here:
[image: Noteshelf scroll bar]

My Collection view is a simple collection view with a label for every cell:

[image: collection view]

Comment: Sorry if I've made some mistakes with the language, I'm italian

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Collection view itself has scrolling right?

Comment: @Arjuna I'm trying to add a view like in Noteshelf because with the Pan Gesture Recognizer I can't use default scroll

Comment: Sorry I am not able download NoteShelf since it is not free. I guess you might want to use UITextView for taking notes?

Comment: @Arjuna I want to do something like this https://youtu.be/ET_J51se3k0

Answer (score 1):

Put your note view in a scrollview and disable user scrolling by setting [isScrollEnabled](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiscrollview/1619395-isscrollenabled) to false.  Add a UIPanGestureRecognizer to your side bar and make yourself the target of the gesture recognizer.  In your tap gesture handler function you:

1. Get the current translation of the pan with [translation(in:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipangesturerecognizer/1621207-translation)
2. Use this value to scroll the scrollView with [setContentOffset(_:animated:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiscrollview/1619400-setcontentoffset)
3. reset the translation so you get only the difference and not the total on the next call with [setTranslation(_:in:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipangesturerecognizer/1621206-settranslation)

Edit to clairfy, UICollectionView inherits from UIScrollView so it has all of the UIScrollView properties, you just need to look under UISCrollView and not UICollectionView.

Comment: Okay, thank you. How can I make a "textured view" like Noteshelf? Should I use a UIView or something else?

Comment: I can't see very well from the screen shot; it looks like the "felt" part is a UIImageView.  The actual scroll bar appears to be a series of translucent bars laid over the felt image.  You can make those an imageview in photoshop or you can draw then programmatically with CAShapeLayer  and repeat them with CAReplicatorLayer